# The $scope Variable not updating inside a $http.success

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Im getting the dynamic Header from the $scope.targetHeaderList, im trying to dynamically allocate the column-name with the data for displaying it in a ng-grid, but the $scope.columns.push is not working inside the success. But i get the ng-grid for the columns which i initialised outside the success.

```
app.controller('customersCtrl',function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.loading = true;
  $scope.columns=[
    { field:'part', displayName:'Part '},
    { field:'description', displayName:'Description', pinnedLeft:true },
    { field:'cus', displayName:'CC', }
  ];

  $scope.columns.push({field:field,displayName:display});

  $scope.add = function (headerCollection) {
    for(var i=0, j=0;i < headerCollection.length; i++) {
      if (i%2 == 0) {
        fieldString = "cgDetailsList["+Math.floor(j)+"].cgHTS";
      } else {
        fieldString = "cgDetailsList["+Math.floor(j)+"].dutyRate";
      } 
      var displayString = $scope.headerCollection[i].toString();
      var obj = new tempObject(fieldString, displayString);
      console.log(fieldString +"  "+ displayString);
      $scope.columns.push(obj);
      j = j + 0.5;
    };

    $scope.columns.push({field:'createdBy',displayName:'Created By'});  
    $scope.columns.push({field:'requestor',displayName:'Requested'});
    $scope.columns.push({field:'trainedFlag',displayName:'Trained'});
    $scope.columns.push({field:'recCommited',displayName:'Records Committed'});

    $scope.$watch('columns', function(){});
};

$scope.data = '';
$http.get("autoAuditTargetData.do?parameter=targetData")
  .success(function(response) {
    $scope.rowTargetDataList = response.targetDataList;
    $scope.data = response.targetDataList;
    console.log($scope.data);
    $scope.headerCollection = response.targetHeaderList;
    console.log($scope.headerCollection);
    $scope.add($scope.headerCollection);                
    $scope.targetDataCount = response.targetDataCount;
    $scope.itemsPerPage = response.targetDataCount;
    $scope.targetHeaderStatic = response.targetHeaderStatic;
    $scope.targetHeaderDynamic = response.targetHeaderDynamic;
    $scope.queryID = response.queryID;
    $scope.auditCommitFlag = response.auditCommitFlag;

    if ($scope.auditCommitFlag != null) {
      if ($scope.auditCommitFlag != 'YES') {
        //document
        document.getElementById("commitAudit").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("commitAudit").className = "buttondis";
      } else {
        //document
        //alert( " false ");
        document.getElementById("commitAudit").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("commitAudit").className = "buttonpos";
      }
    }
    $scope.loading = false;
});

//$scope.columns.push({field:'cgDetailsList[0].cgHTS',displayName:'BR HTS'});   

console.log($scope.columns);

$scope.gridOptionsTarget = {
  enableSorting: true,
  columnDefs: $scope.columns,
  enablePinning: true,
  enableSorting: true,
  enableCellSelection: false,
  enableRowSelection: false,
  enableColumnResize : true,                                        
  data:'data'
};
console.log($scope.columns);
```

Comment: The `$http.get` call doesn't seem to be in a controller. Also, keep in mind that it is an **asynchronous** task, so the script doesn't wait for it to finish it's job.

Comment: @Avalanche it is inside controller and i tried updating the $scope.gridOptionsTarget.columnDefs directly. I see the objects are loading into it, but the ng-grid is not updating

Comment: First you have `$scope.data = '';` just before the `$http.get` call, then inside of it you think you assign some value from the response to that variable. But you are not, since it is an asynchronous call, your script execution continues without waiting for the ajax to return anything. You either need to continue your code execution within the callback function or try using a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). Also, keep in mind that in recent versions, $http the support for `success` was dropped and replaced with `then`